# How can I connect Lisk Desktop to my dApp using walletconnect

Tags: wallet-connect

I am developing a dApp on the Lisk blockchain, and want users to be able to connect the Lisk Desktop wallet to my dApp using walletconnect.

there is some info on the [LiskHQ/lisk-desktop](https://github.com/LiskHQ/lisk-desktop/blob/development/libs/wcm/utils/connectionCreator.js) repo about setting up a connection, but I am unable to combine it with the Web3Modal installation procedure form walletconnect's [docs](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/web/web3modal/react/wagmi/installation) to make it offer Lisk Desktop.

How can I make it possible to have my dApp support Lisk Desktop?